# how to open a html file by onclick?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to open a HTML file when I click on an image.

Is that possible?

```js
const clock = document.createElement('div')

clock.innerHTML = '<img src="https://png.pngtree.com/png-vector/20190912/ourlarge/pngtree-clock-icon-in-flat-style-png-image_1728101.jpg" height = "60px" width="60px"alt="NI">';

clock.onClick = function () {
    window.open('file:///Users/puyang/Desktop/clock/popup.html')
}
document.body.append(clock)
```

Comment: there is no `onClick`, there is `onclick` and you really should be using `addEventListener`.

Comment: I tried the addeventListener.```clock.addEventListener("click", function () {
    console.log("clicked")
    window.open('file:///Users/puyang/Desktop/clock/popup.html')
})``` but it says content.js:12 Not allowed to load local resource:

Comment: You'll need to put the file in your web directory and/or use its url.

Comment: The file is in the same directory.....

Comment: Then try `window.open('popup.html');`

Comment: Ideally you learn how to run a local web server. It is easy.